# Is there any way to signin silently without user input in Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, uwp, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am working on a UWP app which use Microsoft.Graph APIs. Every time i close my app then i need to sign in again using my Hotmail credentials for authorization.
I implement this code for GetToken:

```
private static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                authResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes);
                userToken = authResult.Token;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (userToken == null || expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
                {
                    authResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(Scopes);

                    userToken = authResult.Token;
                    expiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
                }
            }

            return userToken;
        }
```

But every time i reopen my app then AcquireTokenSilentAsync() method threw an exception and ultimately i have to go through the sign in process and give my app bunch of permissions. Is there any silent authentication method available which can authorize my app without the signin process.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running into a problem with Hotmail's security features and authentication methods.  While this maybe convenient for you I would just sign in and deal with the hassle as this creates a lot of security issues.  If someone exploited your program they would be automatically signed in imagine the security risks this could pose for you.  Never sacrifice security for convenience when coding!

Comment: But if the permission are limited like only Read.AppFolder and Read.WriteFolder then security does not be a concern.